# can I access class variables in an instance via console?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a several classes that inherit from a single class:

```
class Bravo << Alpha
class Charlie << Alpha
```

Alpha has some class level variables:

```
class Alpha 
  @@terms 

  def initialize 
    ...
    @@terms ||= load_terms 
  end 
end
```

OK, all is fine so far. But I'd like to access the class level variables from the console for troubleshooting purposes. Is this possible? I've tried:

```
# inst is an instance of Bravo for example
inst.class.superclass:terms
inst.@@terms
inst.class.superclass[:terms]
```

Didn't expect any of that to really work, just grabbing at straws since I couldn't find any answer to the question. I've confirmed that the class variables are there via:

```
>> inst.class.superclass.class_variables
=> [:terms]
```

OK, I can see that they are there, but is there any way to directly access them via the rails console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost made it :)

```
class Alpha
  @@terms = 'foo'
end

class Bravo < Alpha
end

b = Bravo.new
puts b.class.class_variable_get '@@terms'
# => foo
```

It may look complicated, and it probably is so for a reason: to discourage people from messing with class' internals (*I don't know if it's true, I just made it up*).

If you need this on a regular basis, add an accessor for it!

```
class Alpha
  @@terms = 'foo'

  def self.terms
    @@terms
  end
end


puts Alpha.terms
# => foo
```

Comment: Slightly better would be to use `:@@terms` but you get a +1 anyway.

Comment: @Sergio ok that worked, wow that's complicated though. It's odd when you run into something in Ruby that's really complicated -- usually it's so simple. In C# there wouldn't really be any difference between accessing a variable from the superclass or a variable from the class. :/

Comment: @jcollum: Well, it's not c# :) Updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try `pry` gem, very useful for such purposes (can work as Rails console):

```
$ pry
[1] pry(main)> class A
[1] pry(main)*   @@a = 1
[1] pry(main)* end  
=> 1
[2] pry(main)> a = A.new
=> #<A:0x101ba8ea0>
[3] pry(main)> cd a.class
[4] pry(A):1> @@a
=> 1
[5] pry(A):1> cd /
[6] pry(main)> cd A
[7] pry(A):1> @@a
=> 1
```

Comment: Is it treating the object like a directory there? That's peculiar. If it works, it works.